# How to create a remote Git repository from a local one?

Tags: git, installation

I have a local Git repository. I would like to make it available on a remote, ssh-enabled, server. How do I do this?

Answer (score 365, accepted):

I think you make a bare repository on the remote side, `git init --bare`, add the remote side as the push/pull tracker for your local repository (`git remote add origin URL`), and then locally you just say `git push origin master`. Now any other repository can `pull` from the remote repository.

Comment: @Nips: yes, right, sorry. You push individual branches, indeed!

Comment: What if I am using the GUI? How can I set up a server for all repository and each PC on the same network connect to that?

Comment: if `git push origin master` fails with "repository not found" error, try `git update-server-info` on remote side, where you did `git init --bare`

Comment: @KerrekSB is it possible to automatically create a bare repo on server as soon as i run git push origin master on my local

Comment: @HongKilDong I tried `git update-server-info` but I am getting the error 
`fatal: Unable to look up Volumes (port 9418) (nodename nor servname provided, or not known)`

Comment: I find that I have to use the `--set-upstream` flag with my first `push` after doing this.

Comment: To clarify the second command `git remote add origin URL` in a Linux to Linux situation: `git remote add origin username@serveraddress:~username/path_to_project`

Comment: @Tymek Thanks, yes this MUST be added to the answer I believe, so I'll suggest an edit right now. But please also notice that the recommended path to put repositories on a server is `/srv/git` and not in user's home, i.e. something like this: `git remote add origin username@serveraddress:/srv/git/repositoryname.git`.

Answer (score 94):

In order to initially set up any Git server, you have to export an existing repository into a new bare repository — a repository that doesn’t contain a working directory. This is generally straightforward to do. In order to clone your repository to create a new bare repository, you run the clone command with the `--bare` option. By convention, bare repository directories end in `.git`, like so:

```
$ git clone --bare my_project my_project.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /opt/projects/my_project.git/
```

This command takes the Git repository by itself, without a working directory, and creates a directory specifically for it alone.

Now that you have a bare copy of your repository, all you need to do is put it on a server and set up your protocols. Let’s say you’ve set up a server called `git.example.com` that you have SSH access to, and you want to store all your Git repositories under the `/opt/git` directory. You can set up your new repository by copying your bare repository over:

```
$ scp -r my_project.git user@git.example.com:/opt/git
```

At this point, other users who have SSH access to the same server which has read-access to the `/opt/git` directory can clone your repository by running

```
$ git clone user@git.example.com:/opt/git/my_project.git
```

If a user SSHs into a server and has write access to the `/opt/git/my_project.git` directory, they will also automatically have push access. Git will automatically add group write permissions to a repository properly if you run the git init command with the `--shared` option.

```
$ ssh user@git.example.com
$ cd /opt/git/my_project.git
$ git init --bare --shared
```

It is very easy to take a Git repository, create a bare version, and place it on a server to which you and your collaborators have SSH access. Now you’re ready to collaborate on the same project.

Comment: The `scp` solution works IMO better in practice than the `init --bare`. It still feels kind of an ugly hack though to first clone locally, then copy to server... wish git had a command to do it in one go.

Comment: +1'd this one because `--shared` worked for me. I wonder what happens if you use `git init --shared` without making a `--bare` one...

Comment: Create a bare repository locally and `scp` that to a remote works better if the remote doesn't support `git init --bare` (as was the case for me with git 1.5.5, 2008). I think this should work even if the remote has no git at all.

Comment: Reference: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server

Comment: a minor note: the step scp of the solution is correct but it works if the remote user has a regular shell, if the user uses a git-shell it will not work.

Comment: This, imo, should be the accepted answer.  Well put and much clearer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

There is an interesting difference between the two popular solutions above:

1. If you create the bare repository like this:

   ```
   cd     /outside_of_any_repo
   mkdir  my_remote.git
   cd     my_remote.git
   git init --bare
   ```

and then

```
cd  /your_path/original_repo
git remote add origin /outside_of_any_repo/my_remote.git
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

Then git sets up the configuration in 'original_repo' with this relationship:

```
original_repo origin --> /outside_of_any_repo/my_remote.git/
```

with the latter as the upstream remote.  And the upstream remote doesn't have any other remotes in its configuration.

2. However, if you do it the other way around:

   ```
   (from in directory original_repo)
   cd ..
   git clone --bare original_repo  /outside_of_any_repo/my_remote.git
   ```

then 'my_remote.git' winds up with its configuration having 'origin' pointing back to 'original_repo' as a remote, with a remote.origin.url equating to local directory path, which might not be appropriate if it is going to be moved to a server.

While that "remote" reference is easy to get rid of later if it isn't appropriate, 'original_repo' still has to be set up to point to 'my_remote.git' as an up-stream remote (or to wherever it is going to be shared from).  So technically, you can arrive at the same result with a few more steps with approach #2.  But #1 seems a more direct approach to creating a "central bare shared repo" originating from a local one, appropriate for moving to a server, with fewer steps involved.  I think it depends on the role you want the remote repo to play.  (And yes, this is in conflict with the documentation [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server).)

Caveat:  I learned the above (at this writing in early August 2019) by doing a test on my local system with a real repo, and then doing a file-by-file comparison between the results.  But!  I am still learning, so there could be a more correct way.  But my tests have helped me conclude that #1 is my currently-preferred method.

Answer (score 9):

A note for people who created the local copy on Windows and want to create a corresponding remote repository on a Unix-line system, where text files get LF endings on further clones by developers on Unix-like systems, but CRLF endings on Windows.

If you created your Windows repository before [setting up line-ending translation](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings)  then you have a problem. Git's default setting is no translation, so your working set uses CRLF but your repository (i.e. the data stored under .git) has saved the files as CRLF too.

When you push to the remote, the saved files are copied as-is, no line ending translation occurs. (Line ending translation occurs when files are commited to a repository, not when repositories are pushed). You end up with CRLF in your Unix-like repository, which is not what you want.

To get LF in the remote repository you have to make sure LF is in the local repository first, by [re-normalizing your Windows repository](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings).  This will have no visible effect on your Windows working set, which still has CRLF endings, however when you push to remote, the remote will get LF correctly.

I'm not sure if there's an easy way to tell what line endings you have in your Windows repository - I guess you could test it by setting core.autocrlf=false and then cloning (If the repo has LF endings, the clone will have LF too).

Answer (score 6):

> A remote repository is generally a bare repository — a Git repository
>   that has no working directory. Because the repository is only used as
>   a collaboration point, there is no reason to have a snapshot checked
>   out on disk; it’s just the Git data. In the simplest terms, a bare
>   repository is the contents of your project’s .git directory and
>   nothing else.

You can make a bare git repository with the following code:

```
$ git clone --bare /path/to/project project.git
```

One options for having a remote git repository is using SSH protocol:

> A common transport protocol for Git when self-hosting is over SSH.
>   This is because SSH access to servers is already set up in most
>   places — and if it isn’t, it’s easy to do. SSH is also an
>   authenticated network protocol and, because it’s ubiquitous, it’s
>   generally easy to set up and use.
>
> To clone a Git repository over SSH, you can specify an `ssh://` URL
>   like this:
>
> ```
> $ git clone ssh://[user@]server/project.git
> ```
>
> Or you can use the shorter scp-like syntax for the SSH protocol:
>
> ```
> $ git clone [user@]server:project.git
> ```
>
> In both cases above, if you don’t specify the optional username, Git
>   assumes the user you’re currently logged in as.
>
> **The Pros**
>
> The pros of using SSH are many. First, SSH is relatively easy to set
>   up — SSH daemons are commonplace, many network admins have experience
>   with them, and many OS distributions are set up with them or have
>   tools to manage them. Next, access over SSH is secure — all data
>   transfer is encrypted and authenticated. Last, like the HTTPS, Git and
>   Local protocols, SSH is efficient, making the data as compact as
>   possible before transferring it.
>
> **The Cons**
>
> The negative aspect of SSH is that it doesn’t support anonymous access
>   to your Git repository. If you’re using SSH, people must have SSH
>   access to your machine, even in a read-only capacity, which doesn’t
>   make SSH conducive to open source projects for which people might
>   simply want to clone your repository to examine it. If you’re using it
>   only within your corporate network, SSH may be the only protocol you
>   need to deal with. If you want to allow anonymous read-only access to
>   your projects and also want to use SSH, you’ll have to set up SSH for
>   you to push over but something else for others to fetch from.

For more information, check the reference:
[Git on the Server - The Protocols](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols)

Answer (score 4):

In current code folder.

```
git remote add origin http://yourdomain-of-git.com/project.git
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

Then review by

```
git remote --v
```

Comment: At my setup: it will not create a remote repo. This post seems to me just setting up the connection to an existing remote repo instead of creating it.

Comment: This works when you create a empty repository on your domain with same name and then push your local code

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a directory on a remote server. Then use "git init" command to set it as a repository. This should be done for each new project you have (each new folder)

Assuming you have already setup and used git using ssh keys, I wrote a small Python script, which when executed from a working directory will set up a remote and initialize the directory as a git repo. Of course, you will have to edit script (only once) to tell it server and Root path for all repositories.

Check here - https://github.com/skbobade/ocgi

Answer (score 1):

I have a raspberry where I can access via ssh through public key (no prompt for password).

On the raspberry I did

```
mkdir -p /home/pi/my/repo
cd /home/pi/my/repo
git init --bare
```

On my laptop I did

```
git clone  ssh://pi@raspberry/home/pi/my/repo
cd myrepo
touch README.md
git add README.md
git commit -m "First commit"
git push
```

And that was it

Answer (score -3):

Normally you can set up a git repo by just using the `init` command

```
git init
```

In your case, there is already a repo on a remote available. Dependent on how you access your remote repo ( with username inside the url or a ssh key which handles verification ) use just the `clone` command:

```
git clone git@[my.url.com]:[git-repo-name].git
```

There are also other ways to clone the repo. This way you call it if you have a ssh key setup on your machine which verifies on pulling your repository. There are other combinations of the url if you want to include your password and username inside to login into your remote repository.

Comment: how ironic is this....
somebody just downvoted this answer today, and now I am struggling with pushing my files. Looks like I need some git workout to git into it again!

Comment: I think the problem is that the OP wanted a solution to create a remote repo on an ssh server, but you described how to create a local repo from a remote ssh server. You didn't the question answered. (Not I was the down.)