# Why file at remote location is not getting updated by Git version control

Tags: git, networking, version-control

I followed this
[How to create a remote Git repository from a local one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648995/how-to-create-a-remote-git-repository-from-a-local-one)

and this [article](http://devlicio.us/blogs/krzysztof_kozmic/archive/2011/08/20/simple-guide-to-running-git-server-on-windows-in-local-network-kind-of.aspx)

I am trying to create a local Git repo for team of 3 developers with **windows machine**.
After spending hours in vain, I am coming here.

**My Setup:**

I used one of my external hardisk (K: drive with share `\\xyz\gitRepo`) for shared repo.
and C: drive for my local work

To test the version control. I created a test file and commited and pushed.

When I do

```
git push origin master
```

I get:

```
Eveything up-to-date
```

message.

But when I manually go see remote drive content in folder `\\xyz\gitRepo\myProject`, I don't find my new file ever being copied.

I don't get an error so, don't know what wrong I am doing. 
Any ideas/suggestions?

If there are any other such free version control software which are less painful to use, please let me know. Thanks!

**Update:**
I get following error, when I did some more fiddling after reading your answers and comments, now I can get something

BTW: `y:\` is network map for `\\xyz\gitRepo` I created as per instruction from article above

```
Counting objects: 282, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (242/242), done.
Writing objects: 100% (281/281), 3.21 MiB, done.
Total 281 (delta 160), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: unable to write sha1 filename ./objects/pack/pack-e7e1036deac5f7b032db6445f3071dd014076632.pack: Permissi
on denied
remote: fatal: cannot store pack file
error: unpack failed: index-pack abnormal exit
To file:///y:
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'file:///y:'
```

I don't know why it is trying to write ./objects/pack
I thought it should be writing either at \xyz\gitRepo\objects\pack or y:\objects\pack

`gitRepo` folder has read/write permission to everyone.

I am on windows 8 machine.

Comment: You can get a directory listing in a bare repo using `git ls-tree <treeish>`, where `<treeish>` is a commit, tag, or branch name.  The default output will include the hashes of the blobs and trees.  You can avoid that by using `--name-only`.  So `git ls-tree --name-only -r <treeish>` would get you what you want.  As others have said, you won't see the file directly on the file system since it's a bare repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your remote repo is "bare" - it does not have the "work area". This means that your file was committed to repository and stored as object there.

To test if you push actually working check the size of the "objects" directory in remote repo  before and after the push. The size should increase if you actually pushed new file.

To use Git efficiently you have to gain some understanding on it internals. Here is one of the best sources: http://git-scm.com/book

Comment: +1 for useful info. I am going to update my question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

As explained above - a bare repo (usually the "remote" repository) does not show any files.
If you want to be sure that your file was added you can simple clone your project again and check for the file. :-)