# How to use Git to allow multi user edit of files from multiple machines connected to a single server

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, tfs, source-control-explorer

I was using TFS Source Control to store my code in a centralized repository but the only drawback was, I wasn't able to just download a single file and make changes and check it back in. Also, each PC is required to have a VS license to use Source Control.

I was researching on other options and came across Git and I installed in in my PC. I have created a repository and still learning the ins and outs. I do have some question which I hope this community can help me answer.

I have a server where I would like to check in all repositories and allow multiple PCs to download the file to their local PC and make changes and commit back to the server.

Here is a scenario:

[image]

So if I create a new files/project in my PC (PC 1), I would like to commit to the server. Once that is done, PC 2 would like to download that to the local machine and make changes and commit it back to the server. PC 2 would also like to have the ability to pick and choose the file it wants to download locally to make edit.

Is it possible with Git or is there a better alternate to TFS Source Control.

I would like the following function:

- Give the freedom to user to check-in/check-out folder/file/project
- Use a centralized repository server where the user can check-in their folder/file/project
- Can use windows explorer or minimal setup

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes it is possible with Git.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648995/how-to-create-a-remote-git-repository-from-a-local-one

Comment: I want to use GUI, because command line isn't easy for end-users.

Comment: Sorry.. I just use command line but Source Tree seems to be popular and might be what your looking for to set up a remote/bare git repo and is easy to use http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/

Comment: Thanks for the response. I haven't seen anywhere, how to set up a server to host the file. :/ Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this makes it clearer.. Couldn't fit all this in comments!!

**What are remotes?**

Remotes are URLs in a Git repository to other remote repositories that are hosted on the Internet, locally or on the network.

Such remotes can be used to synchronize the changes of several Git repositories. A local Git repository can be connected to multiple remote repositories and you can synchronize your local repository with them via Git operations.

*Note -* 
Think of remotes as shorter bookmarks for repositories. You can always connect to a remote repository if you know its URL and if you have access to it. Without remotes the user would have to type the URL for each and every command which communicates with another repository.

It is possible that users connect their individual repositories directly, but a typically Git workflow involves one or more remote repositories which are used to synchronize the individual repository. Typically the remote repository which is used for synchronization is located on a server which is always available.

Remote Git repositories
Tip A remote repository can also be hosted in the local file system.

**Bare repositories**

A remote repository on a server typically does not require a working tree. A Git repository without a working tree is called a bare repository. You can create such a repository with the --bare option.

## create a bare repository

git init --bare 
By convention the name of a bare repository should end with the .git extension.

To create a bare Git repository in the Internet you would, for example, connect to your server via the SSH protocol or you use some Git hosting platform, e.g., GitHub.com.

Comment: I am using SourceTree which allows me to create Git project locally. Just trying to figure out how to set up the server to host my files so others can use it. Thanks.

Comment: Use a git hosting platform like Github or Bitbucket or a fileserver you have access to. Setup using command as shown above git init --bare.Use the following command to add a remote to your new bare repository using the origin name > git remote add origin ../remote-repository.git

Comment: Try reading this how to setup a 'shared repo' http://www.gitguys.com/topics/creating-a-shared-repository-users-sharing-the-repository/

Comment: I decided to go with TortoiseSVN which is easy to set up and use. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand that (Centralized version control) is somewhat different than TFS .. Below are hints that might help you to answer your question

- create a new repository inside your local machine (which having repository too), this is mainly could be used for any directory whether the project is new or currently existing in you machine

  git init
- checkin is done first locally using "commit" which is pushing/checking in your changes to your local repository (not the central server)

  git commit -m "comment"
- pushing the changes (multiple commits) from your local repository to server's repository

  git push origin master
- Now after the "push", other machines (your colleagues) could get these changes using pull command.
- There is graphical tools to deal with git whether in linux or windows based platforms, discover them out [here](http://git-scm.com/downloads/guis).

HINT: there is [extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/abafc7d6-dcaa-40f4-8a5e-d6724bdb980c) for visual studio that could be used too if you are still going to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I am just looking to have a central location where I can store codes from all users (projects/files) within the network and allow others to download, make changes and update the central location. Some security also needs to be present to ensure who can access what is controlled.

Comment: Also in Git, I create a new repository, how does another user from another PC access that to make changes?

Comment: this tutorial answers your question https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing

Comment: SourceTree Looks like a good option. I created a new repository using Git in my local PC. The guide shows command line. Is there any way to set it up from SourceTree? Do I have to set up drive/folder in the server for all the respositories?

Comment: If you're using windows, you could install git for windows aka msysgit http://msysgit.github.io/ which installs cheetah extension that is helping in creating context menu in the windows explorer itself (RIGHT click in any folder then choose 'git init') ... whenever you push your changes to the server it is automatically creating the folders/files in the its repository according to your physical structure with its history too. you have to read more about git .. it's amazing and it deserves more reading

Comment: Thanks. I have that already. Just couldn't find enough information for a newbie like me, where it explains how to set it up with a central server.

Comment: So I created a folder in my server (`\\my-serv-1\temp\gitrepo`) which I will be storing all the repositories from all the users within the network. In SourceTree, I click on Remote and I enter `\\\\my-serv-1\\temp\gitrepo\` and push it but I get the following error: `fatal: `\\my-serv-1\temp\gitrepo` does not appear to be a git repository.

Comment: better to read tutorials: http://git-scm.com/book/ca/v1/Git-on-the-Server    using HTTP protocol: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/setup-git-server-over-http.txt    using git protocol: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server

Comment: Everything is through command line. There is no GUI way? Sorry but I am new to this.

Comment: I decided to go with TortoiseSVN which is easy to set up and use. Thanks for the help.