# git: sync with SVN and push to another remote

Tags: git, svn, git-remote

I have used `git svn` to clone an external SVN repository.

I would like to:

- push commits I make to a git remote (but not to the SVN remote)
- pull changes from both the git and svn remotes

So far I have done nothing but `git-svn clone` the SVN repository and created an empty remote repository in git.

What would be the additional setup steps and workflow I need here? 
What potential problems/silly mistakes should I be aware of?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there are any pitfalls with git svn but if you are already able to connect to your repository you just have to add another remote repository to your local git an push to that repo:

```
git remote add myRepo URL
git push myRepo master
```

For further information check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648995/how-to-create-a-remote-git-repository-from-a-local-one)