# How to properly initialize a remote git repository

Tags: git

I have a local git server running on my NAS and I'm developing on my laptop and workstation, all in my local network. So, if I want to start a project in a new empty repo, I'm following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648995/how-to-create-a-remote-git-repository-from-a-local-one) and

1. create a bare repo "mynewproject.git" on the NAS `cd ${PROJECT}.git; git init --bare`
2. create an empty 'repo' "mynewproject", also on the NAS `cd ${PROJECT}; git init`
3. make an initial commit in "newproject" `git add . ; git commit -m "initial commit" -a`
4. make the bare repo the remote origin of the current folder `git remote add origin ssh://${USER}@${REMOTEIP}${PROJECT}.git`
5. push to master `git push origin master`
6. delete the 'project' directory `rm -rf $PROJECT`

And then I can clone the `${PROJECT}.git` repo from other machines. This whole process seems overly complicated. I mean, I scripted it,

```
HOSTIP=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
USER=YYYYY
PROJECT=$1

[[ -z "${PROJECT}" ]] && exit 1

PROJECTNAME=${PROJECT}
PROJECT=$(pwd)/${PROJECT}

# create project and .git folders
mkdir ${PROJECT}
mkdir ${PROJECT}.git

# initialize folders for git
cd ${PROJECT}.git
git init --bare
cd ${PROJECT}
git init

# create initial project directory
echo "#!/bin/bash" > ${PROJECT}/ENV_${PROJECTNAME}.sh
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit" -a

# 'link' to 'remote' .git folder 
git remote add origin ssh://${USER}@${HOSTIP}${PROJECT}.git

# push to master
git push origin master

# delete 'project' directory
rm -rf $PROJECT

echo "CREATED PROJECT $PROJECT.git"
echo "Clone with git clone ssh://${USER}@${HOSTIP}${PROJECT}"

exit 0
```

but still, is this the right way to go about this?

Comment: I’m confused. Why are you making a new bare repo and a regular repo at the same time?

Comment: ups, I linked the wrong how-to. I followed http://thenerdydeveloper.com/2018/04/08/how-to-setup-your-own-git-server-on-nas/ ...

Comment: In my eyes the second non-bare repo is not needed.

Comment: Also I don’t think you need an ssh connection for linking repos on the same machine

Comment: @evolutionxbox SSH connection is needed to connect to the remote bare repo on the NAS from the other machines.

Comment: So the script isn’t run on the nas directly?

Comment: yes, it is run on the nas itself. But I thought need to define a protocol for git no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your process is mostly good but a bit overcomplcated. You don't need a
non-bare repository on the NAS, so your workflow should be

1. Create a bare repo on the NAS: `cd ${PROJECT}.git; git init --bare`.
2. Clone the `${PROJECT}.git` repo on another machine. This adds the remote to the non-bare repo.
3. Instead of clonning you can create an empty non-bare repo on the other machine and add remote: `cd ${PROJECT}; git init; git remote add origin ssh://${USER}@${HOSTIP}${PROJECT}.git`.
4. Make an initial commit in the cloned non-bare repo on the other machine: `git add . ; git commit -m "initial commit" -a`.
5. Push the master from the other machine to the bare repo on the NAS: `git push origin master`.

Comment: thanks, yes, actually it is a bit overcomplicated. Still, I'll keep it that way, because that way I can then check out the repo from any other machine and actually start working on it. Otherwise, I would have to add the remote origin at a later point anyway.