# Change a lost git repository in another repository

Tags: git

I have a project developed for a company, the project were into a git. I have the folders and files of the project physically, with the data of the git of company that developed. Now, I need to create a new repository here where I am working. I wold like to know, if it is possible create this new repository and send there, whithaut lost the historic? If yes, How i can do it?

Comment: In other words, you just want to continue using the existing Git repository that you already have?

Comment: Is this what you want?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648995/how-to-create-a-remote-git-repository-from-a-local-one. In other words, treat the existing repository as local-only, and then change it's remote to a new repo at your your new company.